# Multitasking how to make worker thread gain control after calling infinite loop function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

assume creating 3 worker threads by pthread_create,

in these worker thread routine, each call a simple infinite loop function which do not have a return to do counting

how to make worker thread gain control after calling infinite loop function and save the context of infinite loop function for calling in worker thread again?

Comment: The Question is really confusing. can you make it clear, according to what I understand if you wanted the thread to get back the control, you should have put wait on some shared variable (semaphore etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rephrase to see if I understood the problem.

You have a master thread which spawns 3 worker threads which each do a long running (infinite) job.

At a certain point you want to interrupt processing, save the state of all threads to resume where they left off at a later time.

I think the best way of doing this is organize your threads work in transactionally bound chunks. When restarting, you check the last completed transaction, and go from there.

But since I suspect this to be a homework assignment in low level thread plumbing, may i suggest a shared boolean which is checked on every time you go through the loop to exit and store the state afterwards. Aternatively "kill" the thread and catch the exception and store the state. The last option is messy.

Comment: do it work if using a timer to interrupt the infinite loop function and return to the worker thread by a mapping from function to worker thread?

Comment: can pthread_cleanup_push save the context(e.g. the line where we stop, variables in the function) of infinite loop function?

Comment: I am confused now. If you launch the thread the OS will take care of dividing the time between threads and you do not need to concern yourself with the context. It is running by itself. Also threads do not "return" : they stop when they are finished.
As in the post below, polling loops are poor design, and it is better to have the threads block while they wait for more work. With a blocking queue, reading a file or FIFO, a socket, ...

Answer (score 0):

want to do the effect of a threadpool, after calling infinite loop function, each worker thread can change other tasks(other infinite loop function) to run

for example 3 worker thread can run 4 tasks(infinite loop functions)

```
#ifndef JOB_CPP
#define JOB_CPP

#include "job.h"

#define NUM_OF_TASKS 4
#define NUM_OF_WORKERS 3
    void (* job_queue[NUM_OF_TASKS])(void*);
    void (* fp[NUM_OF_WORKERS])(void*); // original running job
    int running_task[NUM_OF_WORKERS];
    int idle[NUM_OF_TASKS];
    int last_running_task[NUM_OF_WORKERS];
    int no_of_tasks_running[NUM_OF_WORKERS];
    my_struct_t data = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, 0};

void func1(void *arg)
{
    int count = 0;
    int status;
    while(true)
    {
        //if((count % 100) == 0)
        //printf("func1 run %d\n", count);
        count = count + 1;
        //status = pthread_cond_signal(&data.cv);
    }
}
void func2(void *arg)
{
    int count = 0;
    int status;
    while(true)
    {
        //printf("func2 run %d\n", count);
        count = count + 1;
        //status = pthread_cond_signal(&data.cv);
    }
}
void func3(void *arg)
{   int count = 0;
    int status;
    while(true)
    {
        //printf("func3 run %d\n", count);
        count = count + 1;
        //status = pthread_cond_signal(&data.cv);
    }
}
void func4(void *arg)
{   int count = 0;
    int status;
    while(true)
    {
        //printf("func4 run %d\n", count);
        count = count + 1;
        //status = pthread_cond_signal(&data.done);
    }
}

void jobinit()
{
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_OF_TASKS; i++)
    {
        job_queue[i] = NULL;
        idle[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_OF_WORKERS; i++)
    {
        fp[i] = NULL;
        running_task[i] = 0;
        last_running_task[i] = 0;
        no_of_tasks_running[i] = 0;
    }
    jobadd(func1);
    jobadd(func2);
    jobadd(func3);
    jobadd(func4);
    jobrun();
}
void jobadd(void (*job)(void*))
{   
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(job_queue[i] == NULL)
        {
            job_queue[i] = job;
            return;
        }
    }
}
void* workserver(void *arg);
void* workserver(void *arg)
{
    int status, timedout;

    struct timespec timeout;

    status = pthread_mutex_lock(&data.mutex);
    while(true)
    {
        timedout = 0;   
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeout);
        timeout.tv_sec += 2;

        sleep(1);
        //void (* clean)(void*);

        status = pthread_cond_timedwait(&data.cv, &data.mutex, &timeout);
        if(status == ETIMEDOUT){
            printf("worker wait timed out %d\n", (int)arg);
            timedout = 1;
        }else if(status != 0){
            printf("worker wait failed %d\n", (int)arg);
            status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&data.mutex);
            return NULL;
        }
        printf("workserver number: %d\n", (int)arg);

        status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&data.mutex);     

        printf("function run %d\n", (int)arg);
        (* job_queue[(int)arg])(NULL);

        printf("cond wait start %d\n", (int)arg);
        status = pthread_cond_wait(&data.done, &data.mutex);
        printf("cond wait end\n");

        status = pthread_mutex_lock(&data.mutex);
    }
}
void jobrun() 
{   
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {idle[i] = 0;}
    pthread_t r1_threadid[3];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)  
    {
        pthread_create(&r1_threadid[i], NULL, workserver, (void*)i);
    }

    int status;
    struct timespec timeout;

    timeout.tv_sec = time (NULL) + 2;
    timeout.tv_nsec = 0;

    while(true)
    {
    status = pthread_mutex_lock(&data.mutex);
    while(data.value == 0)
    {
        status = pthread_cond_timedwait(&data.cond, &data.mutex, &timeout);
    }
    if(data.value != 0)
    {
        //printf("condition was signaled\n");
        data.value = 0;
    }
    status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&data.mutex);
    if(status != 0)
        printf("unlock mutex error");
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: You seriously need to pay more attention to the formatting of your posts.  This is practically illegible.  (The content matches the formatting as almost incomprehensible.

I suspect what you want is to find some library which provides a "producer/consumer" queue so that your worker threads could all make blocking read calls on that (to be consumers).  Then your master thread dispatches work into that queue (or it can be fed from worksers: "feedback").  Blocking calls would be better then some busy wait polling "infinite loop."  Quit events can be fed into the queue to terminate threads.

Comment: sorry, i have already used add sample code function in the web, but after copying the code to the web, it still make a mess, don't know where i go wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clarify your question.

If every worker thread calls an infinite loop then I suppose that your master thread would have to call [pthread_cancel()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cancel.html) on each of them.  From what I gather this might require calls to other [pthread_*()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_setcancelstate.html) functions to set the "cancelability" of the target threads.

Of course this suggestion begs the question.  The vastly preferable approach would be to prevent those infinite loops.  Write your code so that it has exit conditions ... so that the work is bounded by some sort of input or has some sort of event handling.

Comment: After calling infinite loop functions, how do master threads(worker threads) cancel the existing running functions

i mean that when one thread running a task(infinite loop function) and how a worker thread make the task stop at certain point and save the context and run another task and then back to run the previous task again